# DXA 1.2 - Error in the web application

Tags: 2013, configuration, dxa

I am installing DXA1.2 with Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1. I used content porter to import the publications to the CM server since powershell import was causing issues (my environment constraint). CP version is 2013 SP1.

I had placed the following DXA Application Data Definition.xml in my %TRIDION_HOME%\config\ImportExport\ApplicationData and ran the content porter import with the "all-publications.zip" (as shown below). The import ports the permissions as well.

[image]

```
2015/12/04 12:14:49 <16> [Information] Import items into publication '000 Empty' started at 12/04/2015 12:14:49.
2015/12/04 12:15:09 <16> [Information] Import items into publication '100 Master' started at 12/04/2015 12:15:09.
2015/12/04 12:16:07 <16> [Information] Import items into publication '400 Example Site' started at 12/04/2015 12:16:07.
2015/12/04 12:16:56 <16> [Information] Import successfully finished at 12/04/2015 12:16:56.
Import summary
Start time: 12/04/2015 12:14:36
Finish time: 12/04/2015 12:16:56

Total items imported: 490
New items created: 311
Existing items updated: 3
Items partially imported: 0
Items failed: 0

Created items:
/webdav/000%20Empty
/webdav/000%20Empty/Home

/webdav/100%20Master/Building%20Blocks/Modules/Core/Editor
/webdav/100%20Master/Building%20Blocks/Modules/Core/Editor/Schemas
/webdav/100%20Master/Building%20Blocks/Modules/Core/Editor/Schemas/Article.xsd (with 'http://www.sdl.com/tridion/SemanticMapping/typeof' application data)

/webdav/100%20Master/Building%20Blocks/Modules/Core/Editor/Schemas/Embedded/Link.xsd (with 'http://www.sdl.com/tridion/SemanticMapping/typeof' application data)
/webdav/100%20Master/Building%20Blocks/Modules/Core/Editor/Schemas/Image.xsd (with 'http://www.sdl.com/tridion/SemanticMapping/typeof' application data)
/webdav/100%20Master/Building%20Blocks/Modules/Core/Editor/Schemas/News%20Article.xsd (with 'http://www.sdl.com/tridion/SemanticMapping/typeof' application data)
2015/12/04 12:16:57 <16> [Information] Import process 'BLAH
```

Upon successful publishing of all the pages and the web application configuration, I am receiving the following exception while trying to retrieve a page from the web application. The site is partially up

```
2015-12-04 14:21:12,442 [10] ERROR - Semantic vocabulary not found for prefix 's'
System.Exception: Semantic vocabulary not found for prefix 's'
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Controllers.BaseController.EnrichModel(ViewModel model) in c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App .NET\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Controllers\BaseController.cs:line 79
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Controllers.EntityController.Entity(EntityModel entity, Int32 containerSize) in c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App .NET\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Controllers\EntityController.cs:line 18
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass48.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__41()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

This is an OOTB install with no additional content or pages being deployed. I wanted to get some feedback from the community before trying Bart's custom page solution but not sure why it does not work, in the first place.

**UPDATE - MY ENVIRONMENTAL CONSTRAINT using powerShell**

Option 1 
Using HTTPS and friendly Name :

```
Get-CoreServiceClient : Exception calling "GetCurrentUser" with "0" argument(s): "The HTTP
request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication
header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'."
```

This is expected since the installation supports WINDOWS and BASIC Authentication only.

Option 2
Using HTTPS and windows authentication and localhost

```
VERBOSE: https://localhost/webservices/CoreService2013.svc/wsHttp
Get-CoreServiceClient : Exception calling "GetCurrentUser" with "0" argument(s): "Could not
establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority 'localhost'."
```

Since my certificate does not have localhost, obviously.

Option 3 
Using HTTPS and adding server name to the certificate

```
Get-CoreServiceClient : Exception calling "GetCurrentUser" with "0" argument(s): "There was no
endpoint listening at
https://MYSERVERNAME/webservices/CoreService2013.svc/wsHttp that could
accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See
InnerException, if present, for more details."
```

Though I am able to create the service using the browser

Option 4
Using HTTP and localhost (the farthest I got)

```
VERBOSE: http://localhost/webservices/ImportExportService2013.svc/streamUpload_basicHttp
~MYLOCATION\SDL\SDL Digital Experience Accelerator v1.2
.NET\import\import.ps1 : Exception calling "UploadPackageStream" with "1" argument(s): "There
was no endpoint listening at
http://localhost/webservices/ImportExportService2013.svc/streamUpload_basicHttp that could
accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See
InnerException, if present, for more details."
At line:1 char:1
+ .\import.ps1 -importType all-publications -cmsUrl "http://localhost/" -cmsUserNa ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [import.ps1], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EndpointNotFoundException,import.ps1
```

OOTB content porter completed since I noticed the CP package with the install and it was using ImportExport service as well

Comment: It appears that for some reason you are missing the vocabulary application data. I'll have to double check on Monday if it actually is there in the export package, if it is then I wouldn't know from a distance why it isn't imported.

Comment: That was quick. Thanks Bart. I will wait for your feedback and look into alternatives between now and then!

Comment: Found a computer and quickly checked, there is a `0-0-0.xml` file in the `all-publications.zip` so that part appears correct, can double check on Monday of an install works for me. So it does look like there is something going wrong in your import. Don't have a clue from a distance what it could be (application data file not in the correct location for some reason, outscaled CMS etc.) I'd restart the server and try again and if that doesn't help, manually add the app data via the mentioned custom page.

Comment: I see the 0-0-0.xml in my import package as well. I just restarted and tried again but that did not help. The application data file is picked up correctly since some are being set (per the logs above). When you install on Monday, can you try Content porter mode of installation vs. powershell. I will look into custom page configuration as well. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm curious what your "environment constraints" are that make you use CP instead of the DXA PowerShell script. Note that since DXA 1.2, that script supports HTTPS, basic auth and custom credentials, so I expect it to be usable for all security configurations.

Comment: Adding constraints to the questions as well (if it helps future references). Hope it helps!

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the import/export service and core service are configured server-side? From the error messages, it seems like some endpoints use HTTPS and others don't?  Option 1 is not clear to me; can you elaborate? Regarding option 2: is the certificate's root CA trusted on the client? In case of a self-signed certificate: is it in the Trusted People store?   Option 4 is not really an option if your server is configured for HTTPS.

Comment: Option1: We are using a third party authentication. We are disabling that before I am trying the other options.
Option 2: "Localhost" is not available as a subject alias name in the certificate. Only the server name is and hence option 3.
I just looked at webservices/web.xml and the services are all configured for HTTPS only. That being said, should not content porter still do the above as expected?

Comment: Indeed, using CP should also work. I just would like to understand why the HTTPS/auth support introduced in DXA 1.2 is apparently not sufficient in your environment.  Are you using SSO?  In particular option 3 surprises me; I can imagine the cerificate's subject is the problem in option 2. Option 3 seems the right solution for that problem, but then you're getting an error that the wsHttp endpoint doesn't exist (or is not configured for HTTPS?).  Maybe a HTTP trace (e.g. Fiddler) could shine a light?

Comment: I agree. Option 3 is the correct solution as well. I modified the binding to accept HTTPs (which I do not have much experience with) and got the below exception. I am waiting for Bart's feedback on his CP import, while modifying my bindings.

Value cannot be empty. Parameter name: userName. Component: Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService Errorcode: 0 User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE StackTrace Information Details: at Tridion.CommonUtilities.AssertArgumentNotNullOrEmpty(Object paramValue, String paramName)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution that I found. If you are using content porter to import the content, it DOES NOT do the Semantic Mapping for you. You will have to use Brat's custom page here to solve it. Since mine was a virgin implementation with no additional pages, I decided to re-install using powershell (due to Rick's comments :-))

Here are a few things that I learnt if you are using custom authentication and trying to install DXA:

- Disable your third party authentication services
- Enable Windows authentication for the SDL Tridion, WedUI and Webservices
- Disable Anonymous Authentication for SDL Tridion and WebUI
- Followed the Web 8 documentation [HERE](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-8308118F-85E4-4172-B4C3-AACA2ABA96EC) (with SDL support help), especially step 8. I tried with "Message" and "Transport" but was unsuccessful
- Restart Tridion and powershell and try again

Make sure you revert the first 3 configurations once the installation is done. Republish the content and web application works just fine now.

Comment: Good to hear that you got it to work eventually! Note that Windows auth is not required for the DXA 1.2 import script; it also supports basic auth (e.g. LDAP or SSO).  Furthermore, import usign CP should also work (incl. Semantic app data).